# Insert function use with nested list

Tags: python, list

I'm currently working with an empty nested list that I need to fill with elements that all need to be placed in the correct area of the nested list.

It looks like the list.insert() command would be what I want to use, but when I try to use it with the multiple indices necessary I get this error message:

```
nested_list.insert([0][0][0][0], 'value')
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Is there any way of using insert() with nested lists?

Comment: `nested_list[0][0][0].insert(0, 'value')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the list like;

```
In [1]: nested_list = [[[1]]]

In [2]: nested_list[0][0][0]
Out[2]: 1
```

or

```
 In [3]: l = nested_list[0][0]
 In [4]: l
 Out[4]: [1]
```

Then you can use as you like;

```
In [5]: l.append(1)

In [6]: l
Out[6]: [1, 1]

In [8]: l.insert(0,6)

In [9]: l
Out[9]: [6, 1, 1]
```